# Performant way to get single element from XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xml-parsing

I got XML code like this:

```
<Body>
  <Schoolyear>2016</Schoolyear>
  <ClassLeader>
    <Id>200555</Id>
    <Name>Martin</Name>
    <Short>ma</Short>
  </ClassLeader>
  <Info>
     some very useful information :)
  </Info>
</Body>
```

I only need one tag, e. g. SchoolYear

I tried this:

```
foreach (XElement element in Document.Descendants("Schoolyear"))
{
   myDestinationVariable = element.Value;
}
```

It works, but I think maybe there is a more performant and easier solution.

Comment: Have you tried calling `FirstOrDefault()` instead? No need for a loop here...

Comment: xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/body/Schoolyear").InnerText

Comment: I believe FirstOrDefault() in-turn uses a foreach inside itself. So its better to go with SelectSingleNode considering the performance.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas but i would like to lern a good solution in Linq does someone have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take it using `LINQ` or just use `Element` with the specified XName

Add namespace

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

And use one of these examples

```
        string xml = @"<Body>
  <Schoolyear>2016</Schoolyear>
  <ClassLeader>
    <Id>200555</Id>
    <Name>Martin</Name>
    <Short>ma</Short>
  </ClassLeader>
  <Info>
     some very useful information :)
  </Info>
</Body>";

 XDocument dox = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 var exampl1 = dox.Element("Body").Element("Schoolyear").Value;

 var exampl2 = dox.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "Schoolyear").Value;
```

Comment: thank you it worked but is ist faster then my code ?